# A proof involving a quadratic

Tags: proof-writing, roots, quadratics

Assume we have the equation:

$$c = (a-n)(b-n)$$

where `a`, `b` and `c` are constants.

Solving for `n`, we find:

$$n = \frac{a+b \pm \sqrt{a^2 -2ab + b^2 + 4c} }{2}$$

Let `z` be the the minimum absolute value of the roots. Can we prove `0 < z < a` and `0 < z < b` for all `n`?

For example, let `a=150`, `b=100` and `c=10,000`, then:

$$10,000 = (150-n)(100-n)$$

The roots are:

$$n=228.07...$$

and

$$n=21.92...$$

Then:

$$z = min(abs(228.07), abs(21.92)) = 21.92$$

By brute force I see `0 < z < a` and `0 < z < b` for all `n`, but I can't prove it analytically

Comment: For equations with real roots, have you tried sketching the parabola $y=(a-x)(b-x)$ and the line $y=c$ on the same graph for different values of the constants?

Answer (score 1):

Can we prove that $0 < z < a$ and $0 < z < b$ for all $n$?

I guess you meant to ask: Can we prove that $0 < z < a$ and $0 < z < b$ for all $c$?

It is not possible for all $c$.

If $c = 0$, then we have
$$
(n-a)(n-b) = 0
$$
and the two roots are $n = a$ and $n = b$.